# How to translate a custom eforms field

Tags: translation, hippocms

My goal is to customize an existing eforms field (to be more specific, the "File extensions" property of the File Upload field), so that one of its properties is not allowed to be empty. In order to do so, I've copied some existing classes and html files and adjusted them to fit our needs. The field is now properly validated and visually marked as required. So far so good.

I've been struggling to get the validation translation to work as desired. Since we're using Hippo 10, this manual page seemed relevant: https://www.onehippo.org/10/library/enterprise/enterprise-features/enterprise-forms/validation-rules.html

It mentions the following: "These validation messages can be overridden ...".
I presumed this to mean that the Resource Bundle "eforms" should be copied over to our project specific version of the com.onehippo.cms7.eforms.hst.messages package (in our case located at: "/src/main/resources/com/onehippo/cms7/eforms/hst/messages"). So that's what I did, prior to adding the "validation.message.regexp.fileuploadfield" translation key/value pair, and specifically instructing our PatternValidator descendant to add the key to the ValidationError instance.

Unfortunately, this new key doesn't get picked up. I tried to change the key to one of the other three or four key variations that seem to be used by default, but to no avail.

Does anyone happen to know how to get this done in a proper way? I'd like to avoid using the ValidationError::setMessage method if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for leaving this so long. All you need to do is to create /src/main/resources/com/onehippo/cms7/eforms/hst/messages/eforms.properties. Which you seem to do.

The only point where I don't know what you did is where you created that. It must be in the site module. Also, your pom must specify to include properties files, but I think that should be the case. Otherwise add

```
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/java</directory>
    <filtering>false</filtering>
    <includes>
      <include>**/*.properties</include>
    </includes>
  </resource>
```

to the build resources in your site pom

I tested this on a 10.2 project and it works.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I didn't realize the eforms.properties file should be in the site module, I had placed it inside of /plugins/customictsplugin-eforms/customictsplugin-eforms-cms/src/main/resources/com/onehippo/cms7/eforms/hst/messages. I've moved it to a submodule of the site module. Still no cigar, though.

Comment: I would expect that to work. I'd have to see what you did, most likely it is something simple that is obvious once you see it (like always).

Comment: Although you were probably right about me overlooking something obvious, I eventually solved this issue by creating a FileuploadFieldPropertiesPanel resource bundle next to my FileuploadFieldPropertiesPanel.html, containing the following key/value pairs: validation.message.regexp.fileuploadfield=Please enter valid file upload extensions
fileupload.property.fileextensions=file upload extensions

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't be more help. What you did should be the same as what I said, but apparently not. Glad to hear you solved it though.